# Question closed and marked as duplicate error

Tags: support

This question got marked as duplicate and closed.

https://superuser.com/questions/631969/install-a-soft-using-only-cmd-exe-on-windows-xp

But my question was not to know if some gnutool could do the same thing on windows.
I just want to know if there is a way to install something on windows xp by using the command line AND if there is an equivalent of wget on windows xp (builtin) with a yes|no response.

I cant see why this got marked as duplicate as the link to teh "duplicate" has nothing to do with my original question.

thanks

EDIT:
readed the whole "duplicate" question topic and it indeed ansmer my question about wget  but not the rest

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> it indeed ansmer my question about wget but not the rest

My advice would be not to ask two questions in one, which is the case with your original post.

Users frequently don't ask about the real issues they are having, but rather about the problems they encounter with the solution *they* think is right. This is the [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). In your case, your question

> Is there a way to install a soft using only cmd.exe (shell) on windows XP?

lacks a bit of context. It's not clear why you'd need to know, or what you really need to accomplish. We require questions to be based on an actual problem you're facing, but it was not apparent what that was.

However, you gave us another question right after that, asking for the equivalent of `wget` in Windows. *That* is something we can work with, and it so happens that we already had a question that covered it.

I suggest that in your case, you ask a new question about installing software using the command line, and tell us why you'd need to know and what you need to achieve. That way you'll get better answers. Or, you edit your existing question to remove the part about `wget` and flag it for attention to have it reopened.